# Is my sorting code consider Insertion Sort (Python)?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, insertion-sort

I'm learning about Sorting Algorithm and now is `Insertion Sort`. I want to write the code base on my understanding of the algorithm first before copying code on the internet.

My understanding of `Insertion Sort` is: to sort `list a`, first create a list containing sorted elements (called `a_sorted`), and the first element is `a[0]`. Then I will try to fit each element of `a` into `a_sorted` (hope that I understand the idea right). So I implement the idea as below:

```
a = [4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 9, 6, 2]
n = len(a)

def insertion_sort(a, n):
    a_sorted = [a[0]] # Create a list contain sorted elements, first ele is a[0] => [4]
    for i in range(1,n): # Iterate through original list, from 1th ele (start from 3)

        if a[i] <= a_sorted[0]: 

# First check if the ith ele is smaller than the first ele in the sorted list (smallest). If so insert it to the start of a_sorted
# For example, a_sorted is [3,4], ith ele is 1, 1<3 so add 1 to the start of a_sorted => [1,3,4]
# Then continue to the next ith element
            a_sorted.insert(0, a[i])
            continue

        for j in range(len(a_sorted)-1,-1,-1):

# Compare ith ele to each ele of a_sorted, from largest to the smallest (right to left)
# If ith ele > jth ele in a_sorted, insert ith ele right after the position of jth ele in a_sorted
# For example ith ele is 6, a_sorted is [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9], then compare 6 to 9,7,5; 6>5 so insert 6 right after 5 => [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
# Continue to next ith

            if a[i] > a_sorted[j]:
                a_sorted.insert(j+1, a[i])
                break

       
print(insertion_sort(a, n))
```

Everything was fine, I got the right output. I just try to stick with the **insert** idea. But when I searched the code for the Insertion Sort algorithm on google. **The code looks completely different from mine** (it appears everywhere so I think this is the standard optimized code for Insertion Sort). Below is the code:

```
def insertionSort(arr):
  
    # Traverse through 1 to len(arr)
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
  
        key = arr[i]
  
        # Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
        # greater than key, to one position ahead
        # of their current position
        j = i-1
        while j >=0 and key < arr[j] :
                arr[j+1] = arr[j]
                j -= 1
        arr[j+1] = key
```

It's shorter. But I don't understand how it works at all. Still, it's not my question, my question is:

1. Is my code still consider Insertion Sort?
2. Is my code as efficient as the optimal code on the internet (time complexity O(n^2) average, space complexity,...)

I just want to make sure that I can use my code in an interview or an exam when they ask for Insertion Sort. I prefer my code since I understand it and write it myself so it's easier to remember.

Comment: The code you found sorts _in place_, while your code creates a new list with sorted results. It doesn't need to copy element 0 because that is already there, at position 0. Try out the algorithm with a physical 'list'; create a few positions on paper that you number starting at 0, then lay out some objects on them that you'll sort (say, by size, or use playing cards, etc.), and see what happens when you step through.

Comment: "Insertion sort" is an _algorithm_, not a specific snippet of code. If your code implements said algorithm (I do not know if it does or if it does so correctly), then your code performs an insertion sort. I suggest you understand the _algorithm_ rather than memorizing code because you can write the code if you understand the algorithm

Comment: Note that growing a list by inserting requires that all the elements past the insertion point have to be _moved up a place_, which has a cost in addition to your sorting algorithm. This is why you'd normally want to sort in place or create a copy of the original list first, and then swap out elements in the list (which the example you found does).

Comment: This video show you a more visual example of what exactly is happening : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGzPmgsI-pQ

Comment: Try this page https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/#:~:text=Insertion%20sort%20is%20a%20simple,position%20in%20the%20sorted%20 part. to understand its algorithm, do not look at its implementation before trying for yourself. and look at @MartijnPieters comment to understand what mistake you done at the moment

Comment: @VMSMani there is no mistake, if it isn't supposed to be in-place this is a correct insertionsort implementation.

Comment: @LMD agreed , wrong choice of word.

Comment: Thank you all. But I read a comment on the answer below, turn out list.insert method in Python have a time complexity of O(n) (I also check on google and it's true). So I think my method is O(n^3) now. Guess I have to stick with the standard code from now.

Comment: @Hoàng: no, it's O(n^2), I was wrong on that count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code is insertion sort with O(n²) time complexity: It maintains a sorted list and subsequently inserts items at the right position in linear time by shifting elements.

The common implementation you have found works in-place (using only swaps). This means it has a better space complexity: It only requires constant auxiliary storage O(1) while you require linear auxiliary storage O(n) to store the sorted list `a_sorted`.

It does so by "partitioning" the list into a "sorted" and "unsorted" part, constantly growing the "sorted" part by one in each step. I've added comments to the implementation you found to explain this.

```py
def insertionSort(arr):
    # after this loop has run len(arr) - 1 times, the sorted part starting from the first index will have grown to the full array length and the unsorted part will be empty
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        # at this point, arr[:i] is sorted; you can verify this by doing
        # print(arr[:i]) here

        key = arr[i] # this element has to be inserted at the correct pos in arr[:i+1]
  
        # Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
        # greater than key, to one position ahead
        # of their current position: These elements
        # have to be shifted "up" in order to allow inserting
        # the key at the right position; this step is responsible
        # for the quadratic complexity as it requires linear time
        j = i-1
        while j >= 0 and key < arr[j] :
                arr[j+1] = arr[j]
                j -= 1
        # the index to insert the key at is j, because arr[j] < key holds
        arr[j+1] = key
        # after this step, the sorted part has grown by one, from arr[:i] to arr[:i+1]
```